# angular-charts 1.0.0 not working like inner directive when element

Tags: angularjs, attributes, element, chart.js, angular-chart

I`m using the new version of angular-chart.js (1.0.0), ChartJS 2.1.6 and Angular 1.5.7

This is my Plunk that works great when my directive is markup as attribute (cht), but does`t work as element (mychart):

`<div cht></div> and <mychart></mychart>`https://plnkr.co/edit/kOZdMwlZczfalQCVWP8N?p=preview

This is a issue?

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your `<canvas>` in a `<div>` when you use directive as element

https://plnkr.co/edit/5vwzVypIKEYtMckHKhd9?p=preview

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot.